# android multiconnection downloading file like idm

Tags: android, android-file, android-download-manager

I'm making a project like IDM, but in android I want to add multi connection to be able to download faster, but I have no idea from where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

Android has feature called service. In service you can maintain task queue, which can be helpful to start with. Please check the following tutorial, which may help [link](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/android-download-manager-tutorial-download-file-using-download-manager-internet/)

Answer (score 0):

You should learn Service specifically for your requirement you should try IntentService.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread pools for your situation.You can find a starting note here[Android multiple thread pool](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html) and here [Running code on thread pool](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html)